# HTTP GET request with parameters

Tags: c++, http, get, request

Can someone tell me what a `HTTP GET` request with parameters looks like? I'm writing a program in C++ that sends the GET request to a website and gets a response.

I sent this string:

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: "+url+"?"+key+"="+value+"\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"
```

I dont know if this is the right string to send. And can someone give me a size with 1 parameter?

Comment: `"GET "+path+" HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: "+host+"\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"` -- The parameters are part of `path`, e.g. `/?key=value` is a valid path, or `/subpage/?key=value`. The host is the domain name of the URL, e.g. `example.com` (without `http://` and without any other part of the url)

Comment: @asasdasd: It's been a while since you asked this, but could you explain what you meant by "a size with 1 parameter"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to [HTTP 1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) document.

It should at least look like

```
GET /?key=value HTTP/1.1
Connection: close
Content-length: 0
(empty line)
```

The characters in URL after host name and port number should be written after the first space in the first line.